# Change window title for ActivePivot Live

Tags: activepivot

I want to change the window title for ActivePivot Live, so that users having multiple Live instances open, can better find the right one.

I've tried calling Window.setTitle from my GinBootstrappers.afterApplicationLoaded method, but that seems to only show for a second or less, before being changed back to "ActivePivot Live"

Answer (score 2):

Found my own answer.
GinBootstrapper.APPLICATION_NAME is public and not final,
so in my Bootstrapper, I can simply add this line to the constructor:

```
APPLICATION_NAME = "My Application Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

The window title is set by the application and it is not possible to change it.